# Solution to $((1-3i)^{8})^{\frac{1}{4}}$ in algebraic form.

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm struggling with
$$((1-3i)^{8})^{\frac{1}{4}}$$
I've tried raising it to the 8th power using De Moivre's Theorem and then finding it's 4th root but the angles are not solvable. Squaring $1-3i$ three times gives $16 (-527 + 336 i)$ which is't helpful either. I know I can express the answer with inverse trigonometric functions but I can't find a way to get to $2(4+3i)$.

Comment: Convert 1-3i to polar form.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is given by $(1-3i)^2=-8-6i.$ Other three solutions are obtained by multiplying that solution with $i^k,$ $k=1,2,3.$

Comment: Your second sentence is wrong. Just $\pm 1, \pm i$.

Comment: I have noticed that myself and corrected. I shoudn't post solutions while watching a soccer game on TV.

Answer (score 2):

When the polar angle looks like it's going to be "ugly", give it a label and continue working out the problem:  frequently in exercises and exam problems, something will appear along the way to simplify matters.  (Real-life problems are not generally as "cooperative"...)

$$ [ \ (1 - 3i)^8 \ ]^{1/4} \ \ = \ \   \left[ \    \left(\ \sqrt{10} \ · \ \left[ \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} \ - \ \frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}·i \ \right] \ \right)^8 \ \right]^{1/4} $$ $$ = \ \ ( \ \sqrt{10} \ )^{8/4} ·  [ \ ( \ \cos \phi \ + \ i·\sin \phi  \  )^8 \  ]^{1/4} $$ $$   = \ \ 10 ·   [ \ \cos (8\phi + 2k\pi) \ + \ i·\sin (8\phi + 2k\pi)  \  ]^{1/4} $$ $$ = \ \ 10 ·   \left[ \ \cos \left(2\phi + \frac{2k\pi}{4} \right) \ + \ i·\sin \left(2\phi + \frac{2k\pi}{4} \right)  \  \right] \ \ , \ \ k \ = \ 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 \ \ . $$

Our prospects for finding numerical values for the "components" of the fourth-roots are starting to look a bit better. Since $ \ \cos \phi \ = \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} \ $ and $ \ \sin \phi \ = \ -\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} \ \ , $
we have
$$ \sin (2 \phi) \ \ = \ \ 2·\left(-\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} \right)·\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} \right) \ \ = \ \ -\frac{2 · 3 · 1}{10} \ \ = \ \ -\frac35 \ \ , $$
$$ \cos (2 \phi) \ \ = \ \  \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} \right)^2 \ - \ \left(-\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} \right)^2 \ \ = \ \  \frac{1^2 \ - \ 3^2} {10} \ \ = \ \ -\frac45 \ \ , $$

The trigonometric values are "a lot less awful" now.  The $ \ k = 0 \ $ fourth-root is thus $ \ w_1 \ = \ 10 \ · \ \left( \ -\frac45 \ - \ \frac35·i \ \right) \ = \ -8 - 6i \ \ . $

From here, we have a couple of choices:  we *could* use the "angle-addition" formulas to find the trigonometric values at the other three angles, or we could simply consider that all of the fourth-roots have the same modulus and that these roots are 90º apart on the Argand diagram, making them
$$ w_2 \ = \ 6 - 8i \ \ , \ \ w_3 \ = \ 8 + 6i \ \ , \ \ w_4 \ = \ -6 + 8i \ \ . $$

[The "angle-addition" calculations would look like this.  For $ \ k = 1 \ \ , $ we want to add $ \ \frac{\pi}{2} \ $ to $ \ 2\phi \ \ , $ giving us
$$ \sin \left(2\phi + \frac{2k\pi}{4} \right) \ \ = \ \ \sin(2 \phi)·\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \ + \ \cos(2 \phi)·\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) $$ $$ = \ \ 0 \ + \ \left(-\frac45 \right) \ · \ 1 \ \ = \ \ -\frac45 \ \ , $$
$$ \cos \left(2\phi + \frac{2k\pi}{4} \right) \ \ = \ \ \cos(2 \phi)·\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \ - \ \sin(2 \phi)·\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) $$ $$ = \ \ 0 \ - \ \left(-\frac35 \right) \ · \ 1 \ \ = \ \  \frac35 \ \ , $$
from which we obtain $ \  w_2 \ = \ 6 - 8i \ \ ; $ the remaining roots can be found in a similar manner.]